Downloading artifacts from coordinator forbidden 403
I am running a project pipeline and in one of the jobs I am trying to get artifacts from a different project via the needs:project keyword in order to fetch the latest artifacts of the specified job.
my_dependent_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "do something"
  needs:
    - project: namespace/group/project-name
      job: artifact_creating_job
      ref: main
      artifacts: true


But the runner will throw this error:
Downloading artifacts for artifact_creating_job (385624)...
ERROR: Downloading artifacts from coordinator... forbidden  host=yourhost id=385624 responseStatus=403 Forbidden status=GET https://yourhost/api/v4/jobs/385624/artifacts: 403 Forbidden token=yourjobtoken
FATAL: permission denied  

I am on a premium version of gitlab, so the needs:project should be available.
I tried the solution here, to no avail.

So the solution was to add the project in need of the artifact to the job token allowed list of the project which holds the artifact:

go to settings \ CI/CD \ token access
make sure the "limit access to this project" is enabled
add the project which needs to download the artifact to the allowed list


Thanks for adding the solution, saved me research time

Thanks for sharing. It was hard to find an answer to this question, and I'm surprised that GitLab doesn't provide better documentation for this.

For me with GitLab 17.3, this option was renamed to "CI/CD job token allowlist". However, it will be removed in Gitlab 18.0. More information at https://gitlab.nersc.gov/help/ci/jobs/ci_job_token#limit-your-projects-job-token-access-deprecated
The notice states The Limit access from this project setting is deprecated and scheduled for removal in the 18.0 milestone. Use the Authorized groups and projects setting and allowlist instead
